# Update Label within a process using Task.Factory

Tags: c#

I have a process which is triggered by a Form in the following manner:

```
public partial class LoadingDialog : Form
{
    public Action Worker { set; get; }
    public LoadingDialog(Action worker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (worker == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();

        Worker = worker;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Task.Factory
           .StartNew(Worker)
           .ContinueWith(t => 
           { 
              this.Close(); 
           }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}
```

As can be seen, `LoadingDialog` is just a small dialogbox with a label and a progress bar.

Well, the label need to be updated depending on the status of the process.

I can not figure out how can i update the label in the `LoadingDialog` within the process (`Worker`).

Any help?

**UPDATE**:

```
using (LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(proceso.start_process))
            {
                loadingDialog.ShowDialog();
            }
```

In case i pass **this** as parameter, it shows an error due to it takes the main Form instead of the LoadingDialog used in the using statement.

Comment: [Consider replacing StartNew() with .Run()](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Answer (score -1):

change

```
Action Worker
```

to

```
Action<object> Worker
```

Start Task with a param "this"

Comment: I trigger the method with this:             using (LoadingDialog loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(proceso.start_process))
            {
                loadingDialog.ShowDialog();
            }
procesi.start_process is the Worker, so i can not put the this pointer due to it takes a different Form from the used in the using statement.